# What benefit do I get from using ApplicationContext?

Tags: c#, forms

Whats the difference between writing a program using `ApplicationContext` like this:

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Test
{
    class Test
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Application.Run(new Context(args));
        }
    }

    class Context : ApplicationContext
    {
        public Context(string[] args)
        {
            //the program
            Environment.Exit(1);
        }
    }
}
```

and standard `Main`?

```
namespace Test
    {
        class Test
        {
            static void Main(string[] args)
            {
                //the program
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Let's say that you have common features for one set of programs and then some different features for different set of programs, but both sets have some common functionality. By using  `class BaseContext : ApplicationContext` you can do common functionality for both and then implement specific set functionality by inheriting from BaseContext. Basically you get same benefit as from 'normal' polymorphism.

Comment: thanks Matas,,, do you know of a good youtube video that shows some examples? I could not find a good one...